# File exist on os.listdir but is not accessible because it is still being copied

Tags: python, file, listdir

I have a python script where `while(1)` loop looks for an image files in a specific folder with `os.listdir`.
If any of supported format is detected it is converted to `PNG` with `PIL` library.
From time to time some other application copies some files (5MB) to that directory which takes some time.
The problem is that `os.listdir` detects a presence of each file at the very beginning of the copying process, but unfortunately those are not usable until copying is fully finished.

Before copying is finished opening a file doesn't throw any exception and checking for an access to the file with `os.access(path, os.R_OK)` is also ok.

Do You have any idea how to make sure that all files reported by os.listdir are usable, so in my case fully copied?

```
import time
import os
import shutil
import Image

#list of image formats supported for conversion
supported_formats = ['bmp', 'tga']
output_format = 'png'
output_prefix = 'prefix_'


def find_and_convert_images(search_path, destination_path, output_img_prefix, new_img_format):
    for img_file in os.listdir(search_path):
        if img_file[-3:] in supported_formats:
            print("Converting image: " + str(img_file))
            convert_image(os.path.join(search_path, img_file), new_img_format)
            converted_img_name = img_file[:-3] + new_img_format
            new_img_name = output_img_prefix + img_file[:-3] + new_img_format
            if not os.path.isdir(destination_path):
                os.makedirs(destination_path)
            try:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(search_path, converted_img_name), os.path.join(destination_path, new_img_name))
            except Exception, error:
                print("Failed to move image: " + converted_img_name + " with error: " + str(error))


def convert_image(img_file, new_img_format):
    try:
        img = Image.open(img_file)
        img.save(img_file[:-3] + new_img_format)
        del img
    except Exception, error:
        print("Failed convert image: " + img_file + " with error: " + str(error))
    try:
        os.remove(img_file)
    except Exception, error:
        print("Failed to remove image: " + img_file + " with error: " + str(error))


def main():
    images_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'TGA')
    converted_directory = os.path.join(images_directory, 'output')
    while 1:
        find_and_convert_images(images_directory, converted_directory, output_prefix, output_format)
```

The output is as follows:

> Converting image: image1.tga
>
> Failed convert image: /TEST/TGA/image1.tga with error: cannot identify image file
>
> Failed to move image: image1.png with error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/TEST/TGA/image1.png'

If I have copied tga files to TGA folder before running python script all is ok and pictures are converted and moved to other direcroty without any errors.

Comment: Does the external tool copy or moves the file?

Comment: It copies that. I can't change it's behavior. I think I will have to store failing ones on some list for further check.

Comment: NP, I just wanted to make sure since copy behaves different from move.

Comment: After reading all comments I've decided to not remove source file in case of an exception during conversion, and introduce some sleep seconds in a while loop. Now I get info from PIL library like:
> Failed convert image: /TEST/TGA/image1.tga with error: image file is truncated (1006 bytes not processed)
but after few attempts file is finally fully copied and conversion takes place.
Thanks all for Your comments!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to keep a list of those files which failed your test, and do another check on them after a while, if they fail again (or up to a certain number of times), you can mark them that they'll always fail and ignore them next time.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there's no notion of file completeness.

You can create a simple loop that runs for 1[sec] and check if there is any change in the file size if so you can skip this file.

you can use the following to get the file size:

```
import os
file_size = os.path.getsize("/path_to_file/my_file.jpg")
```

Comment: But still you can't decide because on some systems (I think, please correct me if I'm wrong) the space would be first allocated then filled with the data so the file size won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect 'incomplete' files; for certain file types conversion may even succeed on the incomplete data.

Have the process that copies the files, *move* the files into place instead. On the same filesystem, moving a file is atomic; e.g. complete data will be moved into the new location. It's just a rename operation.

You can make the move within the same directory even; use filenames that your script ignores, then move (rename) the *completed copy* into place.